# Flutter how to place nested to the center of the page

Tags: flutter

I have this code that I only want to place the image in the center. not anything else.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Image(
        image: AssetImage(
            'link-to-image'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

I don't want to place all the child nodes of the Column just the Image. Right now the Image widget sits at the top of the page. No matter what I do.

Comment: try to use stack in which you can place your widget where ever you want.

Comment: Use [Center Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default A `Column` has Main Axis of top to bottom, Which means your elements will get placed in such manner only, If you want total control over positioning of elements consider using a `Stack`

In `Stack` there are many ways to position elements, I'll show you few of them

**Using `Align` Widget**

```
Stack(
    children: [
        MyWidget(),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: MyWidget(),
        ),
    ]
);
```

This will place your Widget to bottom Center of the screen

**Using `Positioned` Widget**

```
Stack(
children: [
    MyWidget(),
    Positioned(
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20,
        child: MyWidget(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    Positioned(
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        child: MyWidget(color: Colors.red)
    )
]
```

)

The result will look like this

[image]

Examples are taken from a Medium Article and in general you can find tons of good articles about layout in Flutter , Consider reading them !
Happy Fluttering !